# Auto scrolling to last inserted row in Gridview asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, gridview, scroll

I have a gridview with bulk data content in a web form. When I inserted a new row from another page and if insertion was successful, then the user would get back to the Gridview displaying page. BUt due to bulk data, it is difficult to identify last inserted row.

Is there any simple way for Auto scroll to the last inserted row in Gridview?

Answer (score 1):

I assume it's asp.net.

Use [FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.firstdisplayedscrollingrowindex(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
gridView.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = gridView.RowCount - 1
```